# Eclipse maven - product not installing my plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I recently upgraded a plugin from 3.x to 4.x. When I launch the product via Eclipse, it all seems to be working fine and the IDE has the changes contributed from my plugin. I exported it via PDE and that also works fine. But my final builds are done via maven and it does not seem to be working correctly from there.

When I build via maven, the IDE seems to have no contributions from my plugin nor does it look like 4.x
I compared the list of exported plugins via the PDE and maven; they are exactly the same. I am not sure why then it is not working when I build it using maven.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are probably the start levels and the autostart configuration in your product file. The PDE has some magic defaults here that Tycho (and p2 publisher used by Tycho) doesn't have.

Comment: Right now this is just a pointer - hopefully I'll get round to making this a full answer eventually.

Comment: Thank you oberlies. For the moment I got it to work. It seemed to be the java versions that I had in tycho and eclipse were clashing. It was just strange because maven built everything and didnt complain about it. So through trial and error I found it to be the JRE version